# How to remove files based on their extension using ssh

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, file-management

I need to removed files in my folders that ends in .txt using ssh. This is what I have tried so far:

```
find /models/ -name *.txt" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Inside these main folder model I have hundreds of subfolders with a file that ends in .txt and they need to be removed.

Comment: You missed a quote before `*.txt"`. Not sure if that's a typo here or...

Answer (score 4):

`-type d` means directory, so what you're doing is removing all *directories* ending in `.txt`. `-type f` will give you files.

Answer (score 3):

You also have a problem with ":

try:

```
find models/ -name "*.txt" -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you guys I was avialble to removed those text files saved me hours of ftp folder by folder apreciated